# What does '$P$-almost-surely unique' mean?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, terminology, almost-everywhere, radon-nikodym

I'm reviewing the Radon-Nikodym Theorem. The theorem says:

> If $Q\ll P$, then there are exist a integrable random variable $\epsilon$ that is $P$-almost-surely unique, and it is such that for each event $A$:
> $$Q(A)=\int_A \epsilon\,  dP $$

My question: In this context what mean **P-almost-surely unique**?

Comment: This means that if $\epsilon'$ is another such random variable then $\epsilon=\epsilon'$ almost surely according to the measure $P$.

Comment: how according to P? what mean this?

Comment: This means $P(\epsilon\ne\epsilon')=0$. The set of the points where they are not equal has $P$ measure $0$.

Comment: See also the Wikipedia plot summary for [Radon-Nikodym theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem#Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_derivative)—in particular, the section linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\epsilon, \epsilon'$ in your case both satisfy Radon-Nikodym, then $\epsilon = \epsilon'$ up to some $P$-null-set. That is, it only differs by some set $A$, where $P(A)=0$.